# PHP imagecreatefromjpeg and imagecopy creates Pixelate and very poor quality on images

Tags: php, image-processing, gd

After using this code (just the part working with images)

```
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
$new_width = $thumbnail_width;
$new_height = $thumbnail_height;
$start_width = 0;
$start_height = 0;
$start_width = ($thumbnail_width - $image_params[0]) / 2;
$start_height = ($thumbnail_height - $image_params[1]) / 2;
imagecopy($image_res, $image, $start_width, $start_height, 0, 0, $image_params[0], $image_params[1]);
```

Im getting very very poor pixelate result, you can see it here
[image]

And here is the original image

[image]

PHP Version 5.3.18

GD Version bundled (2.0.34 compatible)

Using GD is a must for me. This example is working very good on many servers, but on some i get this terrible result, and i want to know the reason.

Any help please ?

Answer (score 6):

I have solved same problem when specify % of quality.

```
imagejpeg($im, 'watemark.jpg', 100);
```

or 75 for lower etc.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify quality percentage in imagejpeg(). 
Also, you could use imagecopyresampled() instead of imagecopy().

```
imagecopyresampled($new_image,$old_image,0,0,0,0,$new_width,$new_height,$image_width,$image_height);
imagejpeg($new_image,$image,100);
```